# How to Configure AWS RDS for a Spring Boot Project Running on an EC2 Instance?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an AWS EC2 Linux instance running a jar from my Spring Boot Project. I created a an AWS RDS Postgres instance, and I am trying to call it from within my service that's running in my EC2 instance. I'm mainly running into configuration issues. Below, I am trying to do the following configuration in my spring application.properties file:

```
cloud.aws.rds.capstoneinstance
cloud.aws.rds.capstoneinstance.password = mypassword
cloud.aws.rds.capstoneinstance.username = myusername
cloud.aws.rds.capstoneinstance.readReplicaSupport = true
cloud.aws.rds.capstoneinstance.databaseName = mydbname
```

Here's my Gradle import:

```
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-jdbc:2.1.2.RELEASE")
```

My program won't even run, but I believe that's just because spring is looking for 'spring.datasource.url' etc.

Here's the output:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS Aurora RDS cluster (Aurora Engine), rather than directly AWS RDS Postgres (Postgres Engine) then the AWS cloud driver doesn't seems to support the functionality.

More details and Please bump up if this feature is important to you. It is on their roadmap for a long time.
https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/issues/50

Answer (score -1):

Use the JDBC configuration for your project.

```
package com.objectone.indeskarchive.config;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * @author stelansimonsz
 */
@Configuration
public class JdbcAuroraDatasourceConfiguration {

    @Value("${aurora.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${aurora.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${aurora.datasource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${aurora.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${aurora.datasource.max-pool-size}")
    private int maxPoolSize;

    @Bean(name = "mysqlDataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        hikariConfig.setUsername(username);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(password);
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(url);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean(name = "mysqlJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("mysqlDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "namedParameterJdbcTemplate")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("mysqlDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```